# issue with session storage

Tags: javascript, html, css, session-storage

I am trying to retrieve data from another page by using sessionstorage.

My first page `home.html`

```js
function go_to_faq(qnum){

window.open('FAQ.html', '_blank');

sessionStorage.setItem('key2', qnum);

}
```

```html
<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="go_to_faq('1')" target="_blank"> Open First Question </a>
<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="go_to_faq('2')" target="_blank"> Open Last Question</a>
```

Second page `FAQ.html`

```js
var qpara2 = sessionStorage.getItem('key2');

alert(qpara2);
```

First issue:

At first click on (Open First Question), it give me null. Second click gives me the right value(1).

If I click the second link (Open Last Question), it gives me the last old value (1). When I click it again it will update it and give me (2). So it does not work properly from the first click.

Second issue:

It does not work in IE.

Comment: what does not work in IE? ( BTW IE "died" a few weeks ago and doesn't have support anymore)

Comment: Why do you need it to work in IE? IE is outdated so there's no reason to support it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

first issue is fixed .. I have just to open the page after store the value

```js
function go_to_faq(qnum){

sessionStorage.setItem('key2', qnum);

window.open('FAQ.html', '_blank');



}
```

Comment: You are trying to use StackOverflow as a forum-like community. Stackoverflow does not work this way - it is FAQ style database of "Question->Answer" pairs. By posting an answer you kind of "mark" your question as answered so it drops out of view of experts willing to help. I bet nobody will look for your new question asked in a answer so be ready for your extra question to stay unanswered for years

Comment: It's not a complete answer, but it's an answer nonetheless because the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work in IE which I am assuming refers to the Internet Explorer then you can try using some other browser like Firefox, Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge. Also, I would recommend using Firefox.

Comment: it is a website so it should work properly in any browser

Answer (score 0):

you need to open the page (window.open) and then apply your changes on there !